# Python pandas error in removing stop words

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following code, I am getting an data type not understood error. Help much appreciated.

```
train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].str.lower().str.split()
train['item_description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].astype(str)    
print(train["item_description"][:10])`
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that you are using and full error trace?

Comment: `train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].astype(str)` and try this again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, below my code and stack trace. 

print(train["item_description"][:10])

train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].str.lower().str.split()
train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].astype(str)
train['item_description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
print(train["item_description"][:10])

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c3b526111c8f> in <module>()
     16 
     17 train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].str.lower().str.split()
---> 18 train["item_description"] = train["item_description"].astype(str)
     19 train['item_description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
     20 print(train["item_description"][:10])

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the suggestion. i tried the suggestion but it shows data type not understood.

Comment: @rams: Did my answer help you or is there still something that did not work?

Comment: @shaido Yes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with the data types in your input data. Make sure to explicitly convert everything into strings before doing any operations on the data. You can do everything on a single line like this:

```
train['item_description'] = train['item_description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in str(x).lower().split() if item not in stop])
```